# React context not updating from after promise completed

Tags: reactjs

I have a React context which I am using to manage the authentication within my application. I have done this previously and all seemed OK, but in this application the value of the `isAuthenticated` property is not being updated. I've tried to replicate using CodeSanbox but I get the expected result.

Essentially, I want the context to hold a value of `isAuthenticating: true` until the authentication flow has finished, once this has finished I will determine if the user is authenticated by checking `isAuthenticated === true && authenticatedUser !== undefined` however, the state does not seem to be getting updated.

As a bit of additional context to this, I am using turborepo and next.js.

AuthenticationContext:

```
import { SilentRequest } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { User } from 'models';
import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { msal, sendRequest } from 'utils';

interface AuthenticationContextType {
    authenticatedUser?: User;
    isAuthenticating: boolean;
}

const AuthenticationContext = createContext<AuthenticationContextType>({
    authenticatedUser: undefined,
    isAuthenticating: true
});

export const AuthenticationProvider = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const { accounts, instance } = useMsal();

    const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
    const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [currentAccessToken, setCurrentAccessToken] = useState<string>();

    const getUserFromToken = useCallback(async () => {
        if (user) {
            setIsAuthenticating(false);
            return;
        }

        const userRequest = await sendRequest('me');

        if (! userRequest.error && userRequest.data) {
            setUser(userRequest.data as User);
        }
    }, [user]);

    const getAccessToken = useCallback(async () => {
        if (! currentAccessToken) {
            const request: SilentRequest = {
                ...msal.getRedirectRequest(),
                account: accounts[0]
            }
    
            const response = await instance.acquireTokenSilent(request);
    
            setCurrentAccessToken(response.accessToken);
        }

        return getUserFromToken();
    }, [accounts, currentAccessToken, getUserFromToken, instance]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function initialiseAuthentication() {
            await getAccessToken();

            setIsAuthenticating(false);
        }

        initialiseAuthentication();
    }, [getAccessToken]);

    return (
        <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={{ authenticatedUser: user, isAuthenticating }}>
            { props.children }
        </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useAuth = () => {
    const context = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error("useAuth was used outside of it's provider.")
    }

    return context;
}
```

AuthenticationLayout:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AuthenticationProvider, useAuth } from '../hooks/authentication';
import MsalLayout from './msal-layout';

const AuthenticationLayout = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const { isAuthenticating, authenticatedUser } = useAuth();

    const wasAuthenticationSuccessful = () => {
        return ! isAuthenticating && authenticatedUser !== undefined;
    }

    const renderContent = () => {
        if (! wasAuthenticationSuccessful()) {
            return (
                <p>You are not authorized to view this application.</p>
            )
        }

        return props.children;
    }

    if (isAuthenticating) {
        return (
            <p>Authenticating...</p>
        )
    }

    return (
        <MsalLayout>
            { renderContent() } 
        </MsalLayout>
    )
}

export default AuthenticationLayout;
```

MsalLayout:

```
import { InteractionType } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import {
    AuthenticatedTemplate,
    MsalAuthenticationTemplate,
    MsalProvider,
  } from "@azure/msal-react";

import { msalInstance, msal } from 'utils';
import { AuthenticationProvider } from '../hooks/authentication';

msal.initialize();

const MsalLayout = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
            <MsalAuthenticationTemplate interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect} authenticationRequest={msal.getRedirectRequest()}>
                <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                    <AuthenticationProvider>
                        {props.children}
                    </AuthenticationProvider>
                </AuthenticatedTemplate>
            </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
        </MsalProvider>
    )
}

export default MsalLayout;
```

Theoretically, once the authentication is finished I would expect the `props.children` to display.

Comment: This might not be your actual issue but you have some uneeded flags in a few places thats making it harder to see the wood through the trees.  `shouldRender` doesn't need to exist, as you can simply do `if(isAuthenticating)`. Copying props into state is a common antipattern and increases the surface area for bugs in your code -- as you  are trying to keep 2 things in sync which should actually be the same.

Comment: @AdamThomas Thanks for pointing that out - I think I did originally have it like that but changed it for debugging. You were correct though, having changed this around it doesn't reflect the changed still unfortunately :(. Updated the original post to reflect.

Comment: Where is `AuthenticationLayout` actually consumed and rendered? Would you mind sharing that part as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is `AuthenticationLayout` is above the provider. You have consumed the provider in `MsalLayout`. Then `AuthenticationLayout` uses `MsalLayout` so the `AuthenticationLayout` component is *above* the provider in the component tree. Any component that consumes the context, needs to be a child of the provider for that context.

Therefore the context is stuck on the static default values.

Your capture of this scenario in `useAuth` where you throw an error is not warning you of this as when its outside the context -- `context` is not undefined, it is instead the default values which you pass to `createContext`. So your `if` guard isn't right.

There are some workarounds to checking if its available -- for example you could use `undefined` in the default context for `isAuthenticating` and `authenticatedUser` and then check that. Or you can change them to getters and set the default context version of this function such that it throws an error.

Comment: Hi @Adam, I'm slightly confused by your response but that's probably my fault. The entire application is wrapped within the `AuthenticationLayout` component. Where would you recomment putting the provider? I'm going to update the question to reflect where authentication provider is being used.

Comment: Your components are in the wrong order. `AuthenticationLayout` is accessing the context, but it cant since its being used above the provider in the react component tree. Its basically a bit upside down. You can verify this in react dev tools.

Comment: To fix, I would suggest moving ` <AuthenticationProvider>` up your component tree. Specifically, it has to be *above* wherever `<AuthenticationLayout>` is in your JSX

Comment: Agree my wording was a bit confusing, have edited to be clearer :)

Comment: I understand what you mean now, thank you for clarifying. You were correct, I've moved it up the component tree and it seems to be working perfectly now. Thanks for pointing that out - I don't know why I didn't think of it before!

Comment: No worries! IMO reacts strategy of having the dev define a default context is a bit dodgy. It'd be better if it just blew up -- at least by default. I've had this problem before and only later realised whats happening.